# Can't find class on path DexPathList

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

OK, I am losing my mind over this problem. My project worked at one point, then a friend sent me his copy of my project modified and everything went to hell. Now, no matter if I try to run my version or his, neither works and I receive the same error on both.

```
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915): Process: org.opencv.samples.tutorial2, PID: 7915
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.tutorial2/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
11-04 01:05:02.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7915):     ... 11 more
```

So this is my LogCat output message. As you can see, the project is a modified version of opencv sample so I guess in code should be in check as I only modified the JNI file of the project as this is NDK project.

### **Things that I've tried:**

- Check for project package
- Clean and Build project mulitple times
- Updating SDK Manager
- Changing project target SDK
- Removing and re-importing the project
- Checking all dependencies
- Uninstalling app from device and clearing data

I don't know if any code about the project is neccessery as I don't think this is code related problem.

Any possible solutions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, frankly enough, I solved the problem by changing the location folder from new destination to old destination. Don't know why this would affect the project but it works now.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about how you solved this issue? What is location folder, what is new destination and what is old destination? I am facing the same issue but cannot find the solution.

Comment: So basically if I had my project in `C:/MyProjects/Project` and when I saved the friend's copy to `C:/Downloads/NewProject` the project would not compile, probably because of some settings in the project that I didn't find so I `copy-replaced` the `.../Project` with `NewProject` idk if this makes any sense?